# Cant find missing file while creating new Maven project

Tags: java, maven, spring-mvc, maven-plugin

I am new in Maven and I am creating a Maven project, while creating a project I am getting this error. I have tried googling but can't find the helpful answer, can someone help me with this.

It is saying two files are missing.

Image link:

http://www.tiikoni.com/tis/view/?id=8c33665

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of the error message into your question instead of linking to some vague image downloading site.

Comment: try the new url link to view directly @jesper

Comment: It says the `src/main/java` and `src/test/java` directories are missing. You have to create those directories, that's where Maven expects to find the source files of your program and your unit tests. See tutorial: [Maven in 5 minutes](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html).

Comment: thanks for the link

Comment: @user64099738 Please re-read what Jesper asked of you: [edit] your question and paste the error message as *text* instead of linking to an image.